# Call javascript from href

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<li class="sm2"><a class="scrol" href="#aboutus_marker" ></a></li>
```

I would like this link to call a javascript **and** link to the anchor.

For the record, I would like the javascript to stop the slider:

```
$('#slider').data('nivoslider').start();
```

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Do you want to bind a click handler to the element? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is something called a listener.

```
$('.sm2 a').click(function() {
   // your start slider code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the href-Tag.

Create a JS function and add this:

```
$('#linkid').click(function());
```